# Sub inline_formset django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm creating a Web site to enter the prices of differents products of differents product places(restaurant, Supermarket, Drug Store)

A user can enter many product places A product place can have many products A product place(like restaurants) can have many menus

So I have three models : 1. The first is "ProductPlace" that has as foreignKey the website user model ("User")

The second is "Product" that has as foreignKey the "ProductPlace" model
The Third is "Menu"(like restaurant menu) that has also as foreignkey the "ProductPlace" model
I created formsets associated to these three models in the "forms.py" file.

```
#forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import *
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory, modelformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class ProductPlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nom', 
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'placeholder': 'Nom du point de vente'
                            }))
    num_road = forms.IntegerField(label='Numero',
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput(
                                    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Numero de la rue'}))
    name_road = forms.CharField(label='Nom de la rue', 
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                'class': 'form-control',
                                'placeholder': 'Nom de la Rue'
                                }))
    postal_code = forms.IntegerField(label='Code Postal',
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput(
                                    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Code Postal'}))
    city =  forms.CharField(label='Ville', 
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                'class': 'form-control',
                                'placeholder': 'Ville'
                                }))
    country =  forms.CharField(label='Pays', 
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                'class': 'form-control',
                                'placeholder': 'Pays'
                                }))

    class Meta:
        model = ProductPlace
        fields=['name', 'num_road', 'name_road', 'postal_code', 'city', 'country']

ProductPlaceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, ProductPlace, form=ProductPlaceForm, fields=['name', 'num_road', 'name_road',
                             'postal_code', 'city', 'country'], extra=1)


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nom du produit', 
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'placeholder': 'Nom du point de vente'
                            }))
    price = forms.IntegerField(label='Prix du produit',
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput(
                                    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Prix du produit'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=['name', 'price']

ProductFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ProductPlace, Product, form=ProductForm, fields=['name', 'price'], 
    extra=1, can_delete=True
)       


class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nom du menu', 
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'placeholder': 'Nom du menu'
                            }))
    price = forms.IntegerField(label='Prix du menu',
                                    widget=forms.NumberInput(
                                    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Prix du menu'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields=['name', 'price']


MenuFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ProductPlace, Menu, form=MenuForm, fields=['name', 'price'], 
    extra=1, can_delete=True
)       


#views.py 

def create_product_place(request):
    template_name = 'product_place/place.html'
    heading_message = 'Ajouter des points de vente'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = ProductPlaceFormSet()
        product_formset = ProductFormSet()
        menu_formset = MenuFormSet()
        print(product_formset)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ProductPlaceFormSet(request.POST)
        product_formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST)
        menu_formset = MenuFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid() and product_formset.is_valid()\
             and menu_formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                #extract infos from each form and save
                name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                num_road = form.cleaned_data.get('num_road')
                name_road = form.cleaned_data.get('name_road')
                postal_code = form.cleaned_data.get('postal_code')
                city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
                country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
                for product_form in product_formset:
                    product_name = product_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                    product_price = product_form.cleaned_data.get('price')

                for menu_form in menu_formset:
                    menu_name = menu_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                    menu_price = menu_form.cleaned_data.get('price')

                #save place instance
                if name and num_road and name_road and postal_code and city\
                    and country:
                    if product_name and product_price and menu_name and menu_price:
                        ProductPlace(name=name, num_road=num_road, name_road=name_road,
                                    postal_code=postal_code,
                                    city=city, country=country, acquired_by=request.user).save()

                        product_place = ProductPlace.objects.get(name=name)
                        Product(name=product_name, price=product_price, place=product_place).save()

                        Menu(name=menu_name, price=menu_price, place=product_place).save()

                return redirect('index')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset,
        'product_formset': product_formset,
        'menu_formset': menu_formset,
        'heading': heading_message,
    })

#place.html

{% extends "src/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'product_place/place-input-style.css' %}">

<div class="place">
<form class="place_form" method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div id="items-form-container" class="input-group">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  <h1>Ajouter un point de vente</h1>
   {% for  item_form in formset %}
        <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            {{ item_form.id }}
            {{ item_form.as_p }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {{ product_formset.management_form }}
    <h1>Ajouter des produits</h1>
    <div class='.product'>
      {% for  item_form in product_formset %}
          <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
              {{ item_form.id }}
              {{ item_form.as_p }}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="+ Ajouter un nouveau produit" id="add_product">

    {{ menu_formset.management_form }}
    <div class='.menu'>
    <h1>Ajouter des menus</h1>
      {% for  item_form in menu_formset %}
          <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
              {{ item_form.id }}
              {{ item_form.as_p }}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="+ Ajouter un nouveau menu" id="add_menu">
 </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <input type="button" value="+ Ajouter un nouveau point de vente" id="add_more">
  </div>

  <div class="row spacer">
    <div class="add-item">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Créer</button>
    </div>

<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
    <br> </br>
    <table class='no_error'>
        <h1>Ajouter un point de vente</h1>
        {{ formset.empty_form }}
    </table>

    <table class='no_error1'>
        <h1>Ajouter des produits</h1>
        {{ product_formset.empty_form }}
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+ Ajouter un nouveau produit" id="add_product">


    <table class='no_error1'>
        <h1>Ajouter des menus</h1>
        {{ menu_formset.empty_form }}
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+ Ajouter un nouveau menu" id="add_menu">

</div>

  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dynamic_formsets/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $('#add_more').click(function() {
      var form_idx = $('#id_product_places-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
      alert(form_idx)
      $('#items-form-container').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
      $('#id_product_places-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
      });

      $('#add_product').click(function() {
      var form_idx = $('#id_products-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
      alert(form_idx)
      $('.product').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
      $('#id_products-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
      });

      $('#add_menu').click(function() {
      var form_idx = $('#id_menus-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
      $('.menu').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
      $('#id_menus-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
      });
</script>

  {% comment %} <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.place_form').formset({
            addText: 'add family member',
            deleteText: 'remove',
            prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}'
          });
</script> {% endcomment %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to add dynamically products and menus but i can't. I can add only new product places but i can't add products or menus for a specific product place.

Comment: You need to look into [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: Specifically [passing the instance when you initialize the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view)

Comment: Thank you but i know how to pass formsets instances to the html file. But what i don't know is what to do on the html file(especially in javascript) to add dynamically products or menus